How is the gain of this CS stage (gmRo)^2 in this oscillator?
I was reading this paper which uses MEMS active mode resonant fin transistors for making a mmWave Oscillator. I came upon this schematic for the proposed oscillator in the paper, which says that the voltage gain from node x to node y is \$({g_m}_{M1}\times R_0)^2\$ where \$R_0 = R_m || (Q_{L_0}^2 \times R_{L-0})||r_{o_{M1}}\$
From what I understand, shouldn't it be just \${g_m}_{M1}\times R_0\$ instead of being the square of it? I am not fully aware as to how mmWave inputs/operating condition would affect the gain, but from what I know of frequency response of CS amplifiers, it tends to decrease with frequency whereas here it seems to have grown with frequency.
